# Deleting and extracting of string values in a text node with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i have  these set of xml data

```
<Address>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorDesignator>Dwelling  (Part Of), Null</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Flat  - Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
<thoroughfare>James Passage</thoroughfare>
<AddressArea>Modakeke island</AddressArea>
</Rowinfo>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorDesignator>Flat  - Buena Villa House, 1</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Flat  3a  Anderson's House</LocatorName>
<thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
<AddressArea> Buena Villa Road</AddressArea>
</Rowinfo>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a Funlife Building, 02a</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Offices Unit 2a   Funlife Building  <LocatorName>
<thoroughfare> Modakeke island</thoroughfare>
<AddressArea>Laguna Estate</AddressArea>
</Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

i want to tansform them into this

```
<LocatorDesignator>Dwelling(Part Of)</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
<thoroughfare>James Passage </thoroughfare>
<AddressArea>Modakeke island</AddressArea>


<LocatorDesignator>Flat 1</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName> Anderson's House</LocatorName>
<thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
<AddressArea> </AddressArea>


<LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName> Funlife Building  <LocatorName>
<thoroughfare> </thoroughfare>
<AddressArea>Laguna Estate</AddressArea>
```

Basically in the (addressarea) element i want to extract values with estate and island as suffix. In the thoroughfare element i want to delete values with estate and island as suffix. Any value with house or building is extracted in the locator name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. deleting the text node in `AddressArea` that doesn't end with `"island"`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
     "AddressArea/text()
       [substring(., string-length() -5) != 'island'
       and
        substring(., string-length() -5) != 'Estate'
       ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<Address>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Dwelling  (Part Of), Null</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Flat  - Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
        <thoroughfare>James Passage</thoroughfare>
        <AddressArea>Modakeke island</AddressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Flat  - Buena Villa House, 1</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Flat  3a  Anderson's House</LocatorName>
        <thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
        <AddressArea></AddressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a Funlife Building, 02a</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Offices Unit 2a   Funlife Building  </LocatorName>
        <thoroughfare> Modakeke island</thoroughfare>
        <AddressArea>Laguna Estate</AddressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

**II. Processing of `thoroughfare`**

Just add this template to the above code:

```
 <xsl:template match=
  "thoroughfare/text()
       [substring(., string-length() -5) = 'island']"/>
```

**Now the complete code becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
     "AddressArea/text()
       [substring(., string-length() -5) != 'island'
       and
        substring(., string-length() -5) != 'Estate'
       ]"/>

     <xsl:template match=
     "thoroughfare/text()
       [substring(., string-length() -5) = 'island']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Address>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Dwelling  (Part Of), Null</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Flat  - Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
        <thoroughfare>James Passage</thoroughfare>
        <AddressArea>Modakeke island</AddressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Flat  - Buena Villa House, 1</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Flat  3a  Anderson's House</LocatorName>
        <thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
        <AddressArea/>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a Funlife Building, 02a</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Offices Unit 2a   Funlife Building  </LocatorName>
        <thoroughfare/>
        <AddressArea>Laguna Estate</AddressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

---

**III. XSLT 2.0 solution**

This is easier -- just use in the predicates (of the XSLT 1.0 solution) the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with)**.

Comment: thanx Dimitre,just two left. what is the meaning of this function so ill be able to use it elsewhere "[substring(., string-length() -5) != 'island'"

Comment: @lee, this expression is a translation into XPath 1.0 of the XPath 2.0 expression: `not(ends-with(., 'island'))` . What do you mean by "two left"? I believe this answers your complete question.

Comment: not entirly, look carefully at the first two elements, thier text nodes need manipulations aswell.. i know the expression is XPath 1.0 but what is its functionality. what i mean is an explanation of how the expression solves the problem so i can use the idea to manipulate other strings if need be.

Comment: @lee, What concatenation? I am not using the `concat()` function anywhere. Also, if you remove a coma that is an argument-delimiter in a function-call argument list, the result will be a syntax error.

Comment: @lee, I don't see any other requirements in your question -- please, edit the question and explain. Even better -- ask a new question just for these new requirements.

Comment: @lee, You haven't specified what are the changes in LocatorDesignator that are required -- when you do, then I can provide the code to implement this.

Comment: @lee, I saw this explanation (in the other question) and it isn't strictly defined -- you express *wishes* and not definitions of what exactly should be deleted. This isn't a unambifuously-defined question.

Comment: @lee, The fact that you don't know how to explain confirms that this isn't a meaningful problem -- you haven't specified what exactly strings are to be deleted in each case and this means that there is no rule for this -- if there is no rule, this isn't a meaningful problem -- later on you'll discover variety of cases when you want *something else (different)* to be deleted, that hasn't been specified yet.

Comment: @lee, Could you give me the link to the question that you want me to have a look at -- I am not sure which of your 2-3 questions on that topic this is.

Comment: @lee, Yes, I just posted an answer.

Comment: <xsl:template match="node()|@*">

 [substring(., string-length() -5) != 'island'

an you give me a brief explanation  fo these 2 functons?

Comment: @lee, they do what their name says -- `string-length()` returns the string-length of its argument. `substring($s, $index)` produces the substring of $s that starts at character position `$index`.